# Child div to 100% when parent's height is dynamical | HTML/CSS

Tags: height, parent-child

[image: the problem]

I want the image to be centered next to the text.The amount of text will be different in each box so I can't set the height.As I research people mainly use two ways of vertical centering.Using line-height which I can't use, because I don't have fixed height.Second one is using absolute positioning which I can't use, because left div with image inside will cover the text.If I set padding to text, when image is not there it won't look good.

The best I could think of is to use jQuery to get and set the container height, and then set the margin according to the height.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="image_holder">
            <img src="http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/cat-160x160.jpg" alt="cat" />
        </div>

        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width:600px;
            overflow:hidden; }
        .image_holder {
            width:100px;
            height:100%;
            float:left;
            background:#eaf0ff; }
        p {
            width:500px;
            float:left; }
    </style>

    <script>

        $('.container').css('height', $('.container').height() );

        $('.image_holder').css('margin-top', ( $('.container').height() - $('.image_holder img').height() ) / 2 );

    </script>
```

Is there a way to do it cleanly with pure CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I came up with is to absolutely position the picture inside the box and then  use javascript to remove padding if there is no image in the box.